# Search for Column headers and copy headers to destination sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need a small help here,The header Names are the yellow highlighted row, now if you see the Mastersheet the Address is in C column, if new data comes up then the Address Column might be in D column, hence I want someone to help me to tweak the code which can search for the header names and copy to Destination sheet , I want only selected headers to be copied not the entire column or the entire header row for example only StudentName,StudentID and Section to be copied to the destination sheet

Any Help would be appreciated.

```
    Sub test5()
    Dim Headers As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim SourceColumn As Range
    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet

    Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("destination")
    Headers = Array("StudentName", "StudentID", "Address")

    For i = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mastersheet").Rows(1)
            Set SourceColumn = .Find(Headers(i), after:=.Cells(1, 1), MatchCase:=False)
        End With

        If Not SourceColumn Is Nothing Then
            Headers.Copy Destination:=DestinationSheet.Range("A4:G3")
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: The yellow highlighted Names are the headers]

[image: Destination Sheet]

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Could you be more clear? What does "the header names will change its columns" could mean? Is it possible for you to add screenshots of what you have and what you want after macro executes?

Comment: @J.Chomel please check the above have explained bit more about the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub copyheadernames()

    Sheets("Mastersheet").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("destination").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: this will help to paste entire row headers, however I just want to copy selected header row  for example only StudentName,StudentID and Section to be copied to the destination sheet, how to achieve this through the code could you please help me on the same

Comment: and where do you want the selected headers be copied in "destination" sheet? always starting from "A1"?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I want the selected headers to be copied to Destination sheet in A4 row to G4, the code should also check and validate whether the header names are existing in the source sheet

Comment: not clear to me. how is "destination" sheet supposed to be with regard to possible headers presence?  is it blank, and thus to be simply filled with whatever headers are found in "Master"? or is it already filled with some headers? and in this latter case, what to do with headers already in "destination" sheet but not in "master" one: delete entire column in "destination" sheet? or leave them and notify the user that headers "x", "Y",.. are not in "destination" sheet? may be a thorough example of a "before" and "after" scenarios is required

Comment: Mastersheet contains data of all the columns StudentName,StudentID,Address,Section,grade.The destination sheet is blank sheet,  before copy pasting the header names to the blank destination sheet there are already header names which are selected for my test project, like StudentName,StudentID ,Section,Grade that is `Sheets("Mastersheet").Range("A1,B1,D1,E1").Select` , I would like the code to validate in Master sheet whether these header names exists there then copy only the selected header names to destination sheet in range A1 or A4 sheet that is the code `Range("A4:G4").PasteSpecial`

Comment: I have modified the code got till last but unable to copy the column header names getting the error `Headers.Copy Destination:=DestinationSheet.Range("A4:G3")` in this line **Run time error 424 object required**, hope the above code will really help in answering my question

Comment: just clear the following: 1) do you want to start form a "selection" (as per your original question) or from an array (as per your last code)? 2) what does that _"or"_ in  _"..copy ... to destination sheet in range A1 or A4"_ mean? 3) What are you trying to do with `DestinationSheet.Range("A4:G3")`? this latter is resulting in a fixed range ("A4:G4") and could not match with the "copied" range

Comment: 1) I dont want to start from a selection, you can change it to arrays or range then copy the selected header names in the destination sheet 2) I just presumed that the copied header names will be in A1 or A4 you can copy it to any range 3) Yes you are right, am trying to copy the range to the fixed range based on the count of column header names, however it is wrong, could you plz tweak the code and let me know how to do this

Comment: Hi I resolved the issue @user3598756 used your code to do some changes, the code is working perfectly. Thank you